# @EnableJpaRepositories help me please

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Делаю примитивное приложение и уже несколько часов сижу в тупике, когда я использовал sqlLite, все работало, сейчас я начал его переделывать под postgres, суть Приложения простая:

1. Откроется простая HTML-страница.
2. Можно создать/удалить пользователя и тд, в принципе это не важно
   3.Пользователи хранятся в базе данных.
   Ну вот код

```
package com.example.module11.entity;




import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userStore")

public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}


---------------------------------------------
package com.example.module11.repo;

import com.example.module11.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    public Optional<User> findById(Long id);
    public void deleteUserById(Long id);

}

---------------------------------------------------


package com.example.module11.userController;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/main-user-page")
public class UserController {

    UserDB userDB;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView mainPage() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        setUserForTable(modelAndView);
        modelAndView.setViewName("/mainPage.jsp");
        return setUserForTable(modelAndView);
    }


    @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView create(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                               @RequestParam("age") String age,
                               @RequestParam("idUser") String id) {
        if (id.isEmpty()) {//проверяю если id пустой то это запрос на удаление, а не создание
            try {
                userDB.inCor(age, name);//простой метод проверяющий на пустые \ некорректные значения
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
                modelAndView.setViewName("/error.jsp");
                return modelAndView;
            }
            userDB.createUser(Integer.parseInt(age), name);
            return mainPage();

        }else{
            deleteUser(id);// в этом месте я перенаправялю в метод deleteUser в ээтом мой вопрос и заключается, можно ли так 
        }
        return mainPage();
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public ModelAndView deleteUser( String id){
        try {
            userDB.inCorId(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("/error.jsp");
            return modelAndView;
        }
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        userDB.delete(id);

        return mainPage();
    }



    public ModelAndView setUserForTable(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        for (long i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            try {
                modelAndView.addObject(
                        "user" + i,
                        userDB.findByIdUser(i).getId() +
                                "- " + userDB.findByIdUser(i).getName() +
                                " " + userDB.findByIdUser(i).getAge()
                );
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                modelAndView.addObject("user" + i, "тут будет ваш пользователь");
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDB(UserDB userDB) {
        this.userDB = userDB;
    }
}


-----------------------------------------


package com.example.module11.userController;

import com.example.module11.entity.User;

import com.example.module11.repo.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.module11.repo")
public class UserDB {



    UserRepository repository;
    private static int count = 1;


    public User findByIdUser(Long id) {
        Optional<User> user = repository.findById(id);
        User newUser = user.get();
        return newUser;
    }


    public User createUser(int age, String name) {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(name);
            user.setAge(age);
            user.setId((long) count);
            count++;
            repository.save(user);
            return user;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("err to create user: " + e);
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void delete(String id) {
        repository.deleteUserById(Long.parseLong(id));
    }

    public void inCor(String age, String name) throws RuntimeException {
        if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("age or name empty");
        }

    }

    public void inCorId(String id) throws RuntimeException {
        if (id.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("id empty");
        }
    }

    public int getCountUser() {
        return count;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRepository(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}



------------------------------------------------------

package com.example.module11;

import com.example.module11.repo.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class,args);






    }
}


----------------------------------------------------

application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: root
    password: 1234
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


--------------------------------------------------------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>module11</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

  

</project>

    2024-01-04T17:07:15.306+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.example.module11.App                 : Starting App using Java 21.0.1 with PID 16816 (C:\Users\grish\IdeaProjects\user-spring-data\target\classes started by grish in C:\Users\grish\IdeaProjects\user-spring-data)
2024-01-04T17:07:15.307+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.example.module11.App                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-04T17:07:15.551+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-01-04T17:07:15.576+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 20 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-01-04T17:07:15.943+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-01-04T17:07:15.948+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-01-04T17:07:15.949+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2024-01-04T17:07:15.980+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-01-04T17:07:15.981+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 646 ms
2024-01-04T17:07:16.067+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-01-04T17:07:16.100+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.3.1.Final
2024-01-04T17:07:16.119+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-01-04T17:07:16.265+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-01-04T17:07:16.281+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-01-04T17:07:16.384+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2b098563
2024-01-04T17:07:16.385+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-01-04T17:07:16.405+03:00  WARN 16816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: PostgreSQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-01-04T17:07:16.583+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-01-04T17:07:16.587+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-04T17:07:16.667+03:00  WARN 16816 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserDB' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userDB': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.module11.repo.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UserDB: Not a managed type: class com.example.module11.entity.User
2024-01-04T17:07:16.667+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-01-04T17:07:16.668+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-01-04T17:07:16.685+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-01-04T17:07:16.686+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-01-04T17:07:16.693+03:00  INFO 16816 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-04T17:07:16.704+03:00 ERROR 16816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserDB' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userDB': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.module11.repo.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UserDB: Not a managed type: class com.example.module11.entity.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.example.module11.App.main(App.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDB': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.module11.repo.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UserDB: Not a managed type: class com.example.module11.entity.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1441) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:872) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.module11.repo.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on UserDB: Not a managed type: class com.example.module11.entity.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1441) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:872) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.module11.entity.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:463) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    ... 44 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

html страницы не вижу смысла прикладывать , т к с ними точно нет проблем, понимаю что проблема лежит на поверхности и она очень просто, но уже долгое время не вижу ее,

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык